# Form of cube of an integer

Tags: integers

Prove that the cube of any integer is of the form $9k \text {or} 9k\pm 1$

I tried $a=9k+r$  where $0\leq r<9$
Then I have to put value of r from r=0,1,...8 
Is there any short method instead putting the value of r from 1 to 8

Answer (score 2):

Hint: try writing $a = 3s + r$ where $0 \leq r < 3$. Now you only have 3 cases to consider rather than 9.

Comment: Will it be same as $a=9k+r$ and is $s$ is same as $k$

Comment: $s$ is not the same as $k$. Expand out $a^3$ and see what you get.